# Using inherited method causes unexpected result

Tags: python, inheritance

Trying to find if a keyword is in a title by using a subclass, `titleMatch`, which calls a method, `isWordIn`, from parent class match.

What I want for the `text` parameter seems to end up as the keyword (see output.)  Most of the design of this code is constrained by the exercise, but  I think I've tried every way (but the right one :)

Obviously missing some very basic (no doubt major) concept of inheritance.

```
import string

class abstractBaseClass(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError


class match(abstractBaseClass):
    '''
    get word to match
    isWordIn breaks text into lower case list of words, tries word against list
    '''
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def isWordIn(self, text):
        self.text = text 
        newText = ''
        for char in range(len(self.text)):
            if self.text[char] in string.punctuation:
                char = ' '
                newText += char
            else:
                char = self.text[char]
                newText += char
        lowerText = newText.lower()
        chopText = lowerText.split(' ')
        print 'self.word: ' + self.word.lower()
        return self.word.lower() in chopText


class titleMatch(match):
    '''
    find word in title
    '''
    def evaluate(self, titl):
        self.titl = titl
        return self.isWordIn(self.titl)


title = 'Red Badge of Courage'
abstract = 'foo'
text = 'some long string'

test = match('RED')
print test.isWordIn(title)

test2 = titleMatch(title)
print test2.evaluate(title)
```

results:

```
%run "c:\docume~1\winuser\locals~1\temp\tmpvrnfcj.py"
self.word: red
True
self.word: red badge of courage
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you meant to initialize `test2` this way?:

```
test2 = titleMatch('RED')
```

Comment: There are several subclasses of Match that would be implemented, each with it's own evaluate method, for title, abstract, text, etc.  What I'm trying to do is give titleMatch a title, use the method isWordIn from parent class match, and see if the keyword (RED in this case) is in the title, so I don't think that's it.  Cheers

Comment: But you haven't given "red" to titleMatch at all. How is it supposed to know that's the keyword you want to match against? You've just given it the title, twice.

Comment: Exactly.  In the OP's original code, `test2.word != 'RED'`

Comment: I try to instance Match with:

Comment: I instanced Match with: test = Match('Red'), but, and the sun may slowly be dawning here, it doesn't read my mind and use that instance when I call titleMatch?  The nerve of some languages!  Many thanks, you guys rock.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really complicated way of doing:

```
>>> word = 'red'
>>> string = 'red badge of courage'
>>> word in string
True
```

Python isn't Java you don't need to put everything in a class and in fact you probably don't need a class most of the time in Python. A good rule of thumb is if a class has only 2 methods and one of them is `__init__()`, you don't need it.

Comment: It's for a class (not the Python type:) and the layout is designed as an example of multiple inheritance.  Sorry if I didn't make that more clear.